# Creating Table for Attributes of items in Main Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Im a beginner in SQL :),so excuse me if this is a kind of stupid question.
I have main table containing college names.Each college has number of courses.I intent to create a separate table for all courses offered by each college? ie:each college(data item in main table) gets a separate courses table 
Should i create separate tables called courses for each college in the main table?
Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one course will offers by different collages and one collage will have different courses. so  you need many to many relationship between collage and course. so make `3 tables`

1. `collage (id,collage,other info)`
2. `course(id,course_name,other info)`
3. `collage_course(id,collage_id(fk),course_id(fk))`

say you have

```
collage(1,my_collage,description)
course((1,a,''),(2,b,''),(3,c,''))
collage_course((1,1,1),(2,1,3))
```

you have 3 courses(a,b,c) with id(1,2,3) 
you have 1 collage(my_collage) with id 1
you have 2 courses for collage (my_collage)
  so in your collage_course you have

```
  id  collage_id    course_id
    1     1          1
    2     1          3
```

so you need run query to get all course offer by my_collage like this:

```
select  clg.name, crs.name from collage_course cc join collage clg on clg.id=cc.collage_id join course on crs.id= cc.course_id where clg.name='my_collage'
```

let me know if you have any question .

Comment: Thanks.Could you explain how you relate it each other ? Say i need to print all the courses offered by a particular college,how do you fetch this data?

Comment: @techno : if you get help by this answer then please accept it.